# How to submit ng-repeat data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to submit the form which comes under the ng-repeat directive.I m getting the proper data in JSON format but when i execute the insert query it prints the last data.

For example: Take a view to my code

**In view :**

```
        <div class="row" ng-init="get_membershipPlans()">
            <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="x in plans" > 
                <div class="table-columns">
                    <form method="post" ng-submit="insert_data()">
                    <ul class="price height-price">
                        <li class="grey" ng-model="planDetails.price = x.price">${{x.price}}/ year</li>
                        <li ng-repeat="y in x.plansdetails">
                            {{y.feature_name}}
                        </li>
                        {{planDetails | json}}
                    </ul>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**In angular controller :**

```
    $scope.insert_data = function () {
        Data.insertData($.param($scope.planDetails)).success(function (data) {
            $scope.planDetails = data;
        });
    };
```

**In services :**

```
this.insertData = function($data) {
    return $http.post(site_url + "FunctionalController/inserttData" , $data);
};
```

**In FunctionalController :**

```
public function inserttData() {
    $tablename = 'ult_book_camp';
    $rs = $this->db->insert($tablename, $_POST);
    if ($rs) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => '1','msg' => 'You have booked camps successfully'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => '0', 'msg' => 'No Result Found'));
    }
}
```

In view,using ng-repeat it display three blocks when i print the data in json format ,get result like this {"plan_id": "1", "price": "10" } {"plan_id": "2", "price": "100" } {"plan_id": "3", "price": "105" } but when i submit a parrticular block related to plan_id =1 it submitted the plan_id = 3 in database which is the id of last element.

Whereas in database i have two fields plan_id and price. And i need to insert data in these field for each individual block.

Please help me to get this.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Please check error:

```
Error: can't assign to properties of (new String("\r\n<pre>Array\n(\n [plan_id] => 3\n    [price] => 120\n)\n</pre>")): not an object
fn@http://localhost/ultimate/angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js line 236 > Function:4:371
hh</<@http://localhost/ultimate/angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:293:156
$digest@http://localhost/ultimate/angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:144:43
$apply@http://localhost/ultimate/angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:147:76
l@http://localhost/ultimate/angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:98:419
D@http://localhost/ultimate/angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:103:105
ug/</w.onload@http://localhost/ultimate/angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:104:77
```

Comment: As I can see the main scope array is plans. From this you are taking x and from x.plansdetails. and from this y. And if I check your controller code, you are passing the parameter scope.plansdetails. May be you need to debug the code and assign correct value to $scope.plansDetails.

Comment: I have debug it.n the or which occurs i have edited in my code .
Please check it.